# Pandas df.drop_duplicates() has no effect on multiple identical-like rows

Tags: group-by, format, drop-duplicates

When I run Pandas df.drop_duplicates() in python the duplicated lines don't disappear.
It behaves just as if the three <kbd>3542.87</kbd> were different values (and indeed they are, read the end of my post).

a slice of my data:

```
print(df.iloc[234:237,:])
    Date        Libellé                     Montant     solde
291 04/11/2009  CHEQUE N°9667007                -65.00      5030.93
2   05/11/2009  DEBIT CARTE BANCAIRE DIFFERE            -1488.06    3542.87
131 05/11/2009  DEBIT CARTE BANCAIRE DIFFERE            -1488.06    3542.87
290 05/11/2009  DEBIT CARTE BANCAIRE DIFFERE            -1488.06    3542.87
1   05/11/2009  VIREMENT SUR PEA 3E350018328051 VOTRE OPERATI...-25.00      3517.87
```

My dataframe has unusual dtypes:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 9404 entries, 111 to 8814
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------   --------------  -----  
 0   Date     9404 non-null   object 
 1   Libellé  9404 non-null   object 
 2   Montant  9404 non-null   float64
 3   solde    9404 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 367.3+ KB
```

As "Date" are datetime.date objects and "Libellé" are strings.

After if I try `df.groupby(['Date', 'Libellé', 'Montant'])['solde'].nunique()`

On aggregated row `(05/11/2009, DEBIT CARTE BANCAIRE DIFFERE, -1488.06)` it returns 3 instead of 1.

Do you have any idea on how this is possible and how to clean my <kbd>solde</kbd>  values.

Thanks.

I tried to force float format using `.astype(float)`
And also:
`all4.iloc[233:238,:].groupby(['Date', 'Libellé', 'Montant'])['solde'].apply(list)`
Out:

```
Date        Libellé                                                              Montant 
2009-11-04  CHEQUE N°9667007                                                     -65.00                                             [5030.93]
2009-11-05  DEBIT CARTE BANCAIRE DIFFERE                                         -1488.06    [3542.87, 3542.8700000000003, 3542.870000000001]
            VIREMENT SUR PEA  3E350018328051 VOTRE OPERATION DU    04/11/2009    -25.00                                             [3517.87]
Name: solde, dtype: object
```

Now the question is how to clean these data and avoid this mistake
in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['solde'] = df['solde'].round(6)
```

Solved my issue, however the data were extracted from .csv, .xls and .xlsx files maybe it could explain the bad import : `[3542.87, 3542.8700000000003, 3542.870000000001]`
In hope this would help somebody facing this tricky problem.

After checking it doesn't come from import but from calculation inside my python code. I further investigate and let you know.

The strange thing is that editor doesn't show more than 2 decimals
[vs code variables editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4xtj.png)

Poking around in the code, I came across this:

In:

```
10166.89 + 0.98
```

Out:

```
10167.869999999999
```

Typical floating point numbers issue ! Fixed using round()

Comment: Maybe I should update the title of the post.